# Create new cron job Task Scheduler from SocialEngine admin control panel

Tags: zend-framework, cron, scheduled-tasks, socialengine

I'm new to socialengine framework. Can any one help me how to create new cron job Task Scheduler from socialengine admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task scripts are in application/modules/Core/Plugin/Task in the newest build of SocialEngine and we generally set them to run every 60 seconds at 5 second spacing between scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create a cron job from the admin panel. You would need to set it up with your server. Your hosting provider should be able to assist you. The jobs you will need to schedule can be found in the following directory depending on what task you want to schedule: application/modules//Plugin/Task